# How to create two forms: (login form, register form) and they submitted to my component.and admin has to approve registred user in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

How to create  two forms: (login form, register form) and they submitted to my component.and admin has to approve registred user

Answer (score 0):

You can use default User Manager `com_users` in Joomla , You just need to create a menu then assign the **Menu Item Type** to Login Form/Registration Form under the user manager list and enter the further details and just save it.

[image]

More detail you can find here :

[Help25:Users User Manager](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Users_User_Manager)

[Help25:Menus Menu Item User Login](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Menus_Menu_Item_User_Login)

[Help25:Menus Menu Item User Registration](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Menus_Menu_Item_User_Registration)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but i need my component application user not joomla user it has to store in different database table

Comment: @shilpaih If you have any specific reason ,why you want to create your custom component for user management please specify. Other wise you can use this.

Comment: I am trying to create affliates to my component

Comment: @shilpaih you can migrate your component with user manager to manage your users.

Comment: i dont know that please send me the steps

Comment: @shilpaih I don't know what is your component is all about, how it will work so I don't even know what is the purpose of the user manager in the component , You need see how can you use user manager in to your component as per the requirement.